Can my players use both 5e-2014 and 5e-2024 characters in the same adventure?
In a newspost about the new 2024 core rules it is mentioned that the new rules are compatible with our collection of D&D adventures and supplements. But, as far as I can find, it does not say anything about compatibility with older core rules.
I want to give my players the opportunity to use the new 2024 PHB to create characters for my upcoming adventures, but also make sure the players with only the old books can still play.
Is it possible to run an adventure with characters from both 5e-2014 and 5e-2024 PHB?

I’d say it’s quite premature to be accepting an answer here: none of the answers are actually based on playing with ‘14 and ‘24 characters in the same campaign, and actual experience seems pretty essential to providing a definitive answer here. Yeah, JC said it will work but, he’s said a lot of stuff about the game’s rules that does not make sense.

And a month or two from now, if a better answer comes along based on actual playtesting, I’d rather not have the current accepted answer pinned to the top of this Q&A forever if you go afk.

Related: When playing a legacy subclass from 2014, at what level do you gain your subclass features?

According to Jeremy Crawford*, interviewed by Ginny D, they can. This specific part is at 8:28 of the interview video.

It absolutely will work.

Was his answer when he was asked this question.
Later he explains it works when the game itself is using 2024 rules,

Because the 2014 rules, since they were written over 10 years ago, of course could not predict what we would do in 2024, but the 2024 rules can handle stuff from the past.

As we can see, one of the authors claims that game was designed to allow that.

According to the same interview, there will be a guide how to mix options, like using old subclasses with new classes.

* This interview was "official" in a way that it was Wizards of the Coast that contacted Ginny D with the idea of mr. Crawford speaking in their name about 2024 books. He acted as their representative, not as private person Jeremy, so it probably can be treated as more authoritative than his private tweets and posts. Of course, WotC has a recent history of making decisions and backtracking, so only future will show how it will play out.

I suspect it will take a little bit of effort sometimes, such as trying to use a new class with an old subclass and having to get subclass features at different levels or seeing relied upon class features deprecated or changed, but they look compatible enough mainly.

@SeriousBri according to the same interview, there will be a guide how to do that.

If I understand the interview correct, it means we have to use everything from the 2024 core rules. But we can still use supplements (subclasses, etc) that is not rewritten yet.

Also, in this interview Crawford again insists that the 2024 core books are compatible with older supplements. But he never says that the books are compatible with older core books.

@Tollef my understanding from this interview and other sources is that the 2024 rules are compatible with any individual elements drawn from the 2014 rules. So you use the 2024 framework for how checks, combat, general spellcasting etc works, and it will still make sense to use a class, subclass, spell, magic item etc from 2014, because the basics are all compatible. An old subclass with a revised class is a trickier individual case.

@Tollef core books are not generally compatible, but GinnyD asked him if a 2014 character could just play in 2024 game, and he said yes.


Can my players use both 5e-2014 and 5e-2024 characters in the same adventure?

Yes
You can use any rules you like, regardless of what WOTC recommends. However, the 2024 PHB gives you guidance on how to use 2014 sub classes with 2024 classes. The 2024 Players Handbook explains how this works.

Is it possible to run an adventure with characters from both 5e-2014 and 5e-2024 PHB?

Again, you can do anything you like in your game, but yes, this option is supported by the 2024 rules. If I understand correctly, the guidance is to use 2024 classes with 2014 (only) subclasses, meaning the subclass progression may be different from 2014. If a subclass was replaced, then the guidance is to use 2024 version (both class and subclass).
Where might this get weird?
If you have a player that only has the 2014 rules, and the DM is using 2024 rules, the better part of the rules are identical, a few rules have minor changes and a few rules have more significant changes that may cause issues for 2014 (only) players. For example, if your player has a 2014 assassin, and you are using the 2024 rules, how hide and surprise work are completely different, so you may need to follow the guidance and update to the 2024 rules for this class and subclass.
Tools
You didn't ask, but I assume many folks are concerned about the tools, particularly the dndbeyond character builder. According to the Beyond Ruleset Changelog [UPDATE],

Players who only have access to the 2014 Player’s Handbook will maintain their character options, spells, and magical items in their character sheets. Players with access to the 2024 and 2014 digital Player’s Handbooks can select from both sources when creating new characters. Players will not need to rely on Homebrew to use their 2014 player options, including spells and magic items, as recommended in previous changelogs.

Ostensibly this means the character builder will allow you to do any of the three (use 2024 rules, use 2014 sub classes with 2024 classes, or use 2014 rules). This is all just announcements, however, so how the tools will actually work remains to be seen.
They do, however, mention the following.

We are not changing players’ current character sheets, except for relabeling and renaming. Examples include Races to Species, Inspiration to Heroic Inspiration, and Cast Spell to Magic.


Can confirm that the D&D Beyond changes have been implemented as announced: you can make a straight 2014 character, mix a 2024 class with a 2014 subclass and/or spells, or make a straight 2024 character. Any of these can be in the same campaign together.

On what page in the 2024 PHB does it give guidance on on how to use 2014 subclasses with 2024 classes? So far I've only found rules explaining how to upgrade 2014 Backgrounds/Races to 2024 Origins/Species, but nothing at all involving classes

@CameronCrane If I recall correctly, it's before the classes are presented. It mentions any subclasses that receive features at a different rate (wizard, cleric, etc) now receive their features at the rate mentioned in the class (like 3 instead of 2 for wizard, etc.) Let me know if you can't find it and I'll go back and look at the preview where Treantmonk mentions this (while showing the book, but not sure if you can see the page number - I do not have the book myself). It's also mentioned in a Jeremy Crawford interview, but I'm not sure I could find that again :)

Personal opinion: unless you are playing in an organized competition, where it is essential that players going through the same module at different tables are facing exactly the same challenges with the same resources, there is no point in playing with any specific edition of Dungeons and Dragons. Certainly not in worrying about different releases within an edition. The game master has to understand the rule book The players are seeing - if they are seeing a rulebook - in order to handle their actions correctly, but since the game master winds up deciding what succeeds and what doesn't, outside the player's view, whatever happens is good as long as it feels right to the players and advances the story.
The publishers, of course, care a great deal about the difference between editions of the game. That's their income stream. But as long as you have some consensus on how differences and disagreements will be reconciled, and most importantly everyone is having fun, it's all good. Keeping it "compatible" is it matter of good storytelling, and is largely the game Masters responsibility.
It is not uncommon to have campaigns we're characters are based on rules completely outside the "official" set. After all, that's how all those character classes and creatures and objects and spells and so on were developed in the first place; somebody invented something for some private game, folks liked it, it was refined and became known to other groups, and it eventually got adopted into the "official" system.
This is one reason I have never said I am playing AD&D even when we were using those books as references. I play d&d, or more accurately I play a fantasy role playing game which may borrow from many sources, ad&d just being the base framework we are building on top of.

In a sense, I agree. There is no such thing as "bad, wrong, fun" in an RPG. So if the GM wants to force things to work together and the table agrees, they can. I've done mergers of WOD and COD games a few times that have worked well with a lot of judgment calls.
But I'm not sure this answers the question. It is perfectly valid to ask whether they were designed to work together and how well they actually work together without using insane amounts of GM judgment calls.

If they weren't supposed to be compatible, the new one  would have been called 6th edition... But really, as I said, compatibility is something that the game master applies; as long as each character or item behaves according to its own consistent rules, everything works. It may be slightly out of balance, or a character's assumptions may turn out to be mistaken, but that happens in the real world too. Different fighting styles, slightly different spells, different breeds, different manufacturers, different conditions.

Really, the difference between two printings of the same edition shouldn't be much more than minor error corrections and clarifications. Again, that may be important in tournament play. But it's mostly irrelevant, or easily dealt with, at a single table. So I stand by my answer.

If you could support it with developers comments, experience with the draft version, or something similar, then your second comment would probably be a solid answer. I'm not quite sure the choice of name is adequate support for the answer though.

If everything is made up and the rules don’t matter… well, enjoy playing calvinball, but personally, I play TTRPGs as much for the game as for the role-playing - that is to say, if what I wanted was to sit at a table and do improv narrative storytelling, I’d just do that and not pretend to be involving rules that I don’t actually care about.

The question was, can different players be using different versions of the rule book. The answer is yes, as long as the game master is willing to reconcile any disagreements that come up. I stand by my answer.
